Graphical visualization of disk usage using ncdu output json file
NCDU is a great tool, and I use it often to get a usage report of my headless servers. However, I was wondering of there is a tool out there that can take the output of NCDU (the json file), and nicely produce a graphical report similar to WinDirSta, QDirStat, WizTree and the like?

Update:
It is possible to use html and javascript (D3) to generate a nice-looking treemap from a json file like the one in the screenshot below:
(from https://live.yworks.com/demos/layout/treemap/)



You don't need ncdu for that; simply use the qdirstat-cache-writer Perl script that comes with QDirStat, copy the resulting file to your desktop machine and view the result with QDirStat. More details here:
https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/QDirStat-for-Servers.md

that's a good tool, thanks for sharing. Although it would still be helpful to have a tool that can render the ncdu output for sharing disk usage with collaborators.
